# How to create an A4 trifold brochure?

Tags: print-design, page-layout, print-production

I need to to know what my artboard's size be to created for a trifold brochure. For my own reference I folded an A4 paper manually. So my question is will a horizontal A4 sized artboard will do to have the same thing on print?

Comment: I need to to know what my artboard's size be to create a tri fold brochure. For my own reference I folded an A4 paper manually. So my question is will a horizontal A4 sized artboard will do to have the same thing on print?

Comment: I do not have the size of the final one. It will be 1/3rd of an A4, is all i can say. Basically an A4 sheet kept in an horizontal way folded twice, like an accordion style. I'm sorry that i do not have an image to post or the actual sizes after the folding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably trying to create a DL-sized item from an A4 landscape document set up as 2 pages. In which case yes, create 2 A4 landscape pages (artboards) and take the image below as your guide. Non-printing guidelines can be added where the dotted lines are, so you know where the folds will be made in production. There are 2 options here depending on how you want the folds to open.

Make sure you follow the logic of the folds as you will probably need to send a 2-page pdf with the folds shuffled. If using the 'roll-fold' type make sure you place the 97mm flap on the right side for the second A4 page (the second page will be measured in reverse).

For a ton of other articles and [tutorials](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-creating-a-tri-fold-template-in-indesign-cs5--vector-5452) on this just google 'a4 dl folded' or 'a4 trifold'.

[image]